# How can i make intellij select the code completion suggestion without me having to navigate to it?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, code-completion, intellij-plugin, intellij-15

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.6 with the Ruby plugin.

I noticed that when i write in java, the code completion popup automatically highlights the first suggestion like so -
[image: selected]

this allows me to just press "enter" in order to complete the word and continue.

when i write in ruby, however, no suggestion is selected, like so -
[image: not selected]

this makes it so that i have to navigate with the arrow keys in order to pick a suggestion before i can hit "enter".

i tried digging deep in the preferences and all over the internet, but i can't seem to find out why this is happening. i tried adding the option "insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc.", but it doesn't work because there is no "selected variant"

i know this sounds small, but it's cutting off my workflow horribly, and i believe there are others out there who would like to know how to do this.

thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: I would fire a bug for jetbrains and meenwhile can you try TAB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Eugen Martynov's comment, i found jetbrains' bug tracker site, where there i found an issue exactly like mine. [click here to see the issue entry](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16886)

to make it short, the answer is as follows:

1. open "search everywhere" (double shift)
   [image: registry action]
2. search for "registry" and choose the one under "Actions" this will open a new window.
   [image]
3. here look for the key ide.completion.lookup.element.preselect.depends.on.context and uncheck its box.
   [image]

after the box has been unchecked code completion will select the first suggestion before user navigation.

Thanks again to Eugen for your help